# In Ruby's Test::Unit::TestCase, is there a way for a test method to access the total number of methods about to be tested?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

i.e. as I compose my test suites to include other suites as well as test cases,
is there a global count of how many tests the TestRunner has executed, will be executing?

Any way I can progammatically access that count?

Comment: Why would you want something like this ? A test method needing to know the population count of other tests. Some context would be helpful..

Comment: Agreed, this does sound like the beginnings of a particularly nasty testing smell. Context would help allay my fears.

Answer (score 2):

not sure about how many it has executed, but couldn't you check how many total tests using `self.methods.grep(/test_/)`?

Answer (score 0):

`Test::Unit::TestSuite#size` may be helpful.

`Test::Unit::TestCase#size` probably isn't, as it returns 1.